# Windows 10 is unbearably slow on a HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

I have two laptops from 2013, one from HP and one from Acer. They have one thing in common, the HDD is always at a constant 100%. The hard drives aren't bad, when I don't run Windows on them and use them for regular data transfer they both go at around 60MB/s but when Windows is active the hard drive is constantly at 100% use and everything runs so slow it takes 10 minutes to save a text file. I have noticed Windows 7 and 8.1 actually run a lot better, it's since Windows 10 that they're actually unusable.

What does Windows 10 do differently?

Most disk usage is from System, and often windows modules installer worker comes up and uses as much as it can. For some reason the read and write speeds go to 0.5MB/s average on Windows 10. I left the laptop on multiple days multiple times and ran disk scans and sfc, dism and chkdsk and there is nothing wrong with the OS nor the disk.

How can we make Windows 10 stop doing whatever stuff it does in the background and make it perform the same way previous versions run?

I noticed when disabling CPU cores using msconfig, the disk speeds go up by a LOT. Immediately it's noticable the disk is being used at 0% when idle and you can actually open programs and make files just fine. Maybe the hard drive is being given too many operations asynchronously causing for a bunch of random read and writes making the disk choke.

I don't have money for a new laptop so I want to keep using my "old" laptop. I don't know what to do anymore, this sluggish performance drives me crazy. I punched my laptop in frustration and the hinge is still attached to the corner but the corner that contains the charging port snapped off completely.

The issue got significantly worse when I took 4GB RAM out from the laptop and left it with 4GB which should be enough. It's actually unusable, even though it's how the device came stock. The RAM goes to 90% even when I'm running a single program. This may affect the problem too.

Can we force programs to give other programs a higher priority to read and write to and from the disk? I would like to be able to just block certain programs from using the disk like Edge Chromium update, which is a real virus and I simply can't remove it as it installs itself again immediately using 1.4GB of space.

I am out of ideas, I need to know what other people do to get Windows to take the hard drive easy!

Comment: Any modern OS is unbearably slow in an old 5400rpm HDD.

Comment: 100% I would replace that hard drive with an SSD every time. SATA SSDs are relatively cheap with a [1TB drive](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Crucial-BX500-CT1000BX500SSD1-Internal-NAND/dp/B07YD579WM) being £50. Cloning the from your internal drive to the new drive is a relatively simple matter if you also get a [USB SATA adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Drive-Adapter-Converter-Connector-Auto-sleep/dp/B09K3NB1B6) and once swapped can give a massive boost. I would then recommend taking a hammer to the old drive and being happy with the result.

Comment: From experience Windows 10 also uses 4GB as an absolute minimum despite the "requirements" claiming that it can work with 2GB. The later versions of Windows 10 just kept growing in memory requirements.

Comment: You have our sympathies, but no current OS is going to run well on a 10-year-old machine, no matter what you add to it - more RAM [8GB minimum these days], SSD [HDD is going to be painfully slow].

Comment: A new SSD would help but obviously means spending money you may not have. So I would firstly suggest disabling automatic updates since they can bring a slow PC to its knees. Don’t forget to install updates manually at regular intervals though as you will otherwise be compromising security. Speaking of security, some AV programs can cause a bit of slowdown  - the one built into Windows is OK but more efficient alternatives do exist. You should probably also disable SuperFetch as well. Lastly, defragmenting the disk could help in some cases.

Comment: If you hard drive is as old as the rest of your system, there's nothing that can be done for it.  Think about a carpet in a high traffic area, it just wears out and has to be replaced.  As your as your replacing it get an SSD.  Sure you might get a small improvement you will barely notice, but it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I have checked the SMART status and am kind of surprised but also not. There are 2 warnings on the HDD, and it has 12278 operation hours. Despite that I left all programs I want to use open for an hour or so and waited for all processes to settle and it kind of works. Disk benchmark now somehow shows 90MB/s? I didn't know the disk could do that speed, especially with the age and how much it's been used. The operating system doesn't get to use 90MB/s though, still runs at 1MB/s according to taskmgr.

Comment: @Foxyz The problem with HDDs is that they have massive delays when a program asks them to "look for this", "now look over here", "now here" known as the seek time. For every time the operating system is trying to do more than one thing at once it forces the drive head to essentially skitter randomly across the drive and the time spent seeking becomes far larger than the time spent actually reading data. SSDs have nearly zero seek time and also higher bandwidth meaning that not only can you do a lot more random reads but you can transfer a lot more data as well. An SSD is a good investment.

Comment: @Mokubai That's right! I assume having the CPU run multithreaded also causes way more programs to ask for different files at the same time forcing the hard drive to perform random reads and writes. I noticed that the biggest thing causing all problems is pretty much always the pagefile. Resource monitor shows tons of programs are constantly accessing the pagefile instead of using RAM since there isn't enough RAM in the system. Solution is ReadyBoost or expand RAM and disable or decrease the pagefile on the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to be usable again!
All you need to do is add more RAM. For some reason the latest Windows 10 updates use more and more RAM and there is pretty much nothing of the 4GB remaining for other programs so the computer starts using the pagefile intensively and that just puts your hard drive to a ton of work. I found a 2GB DDR3 in an old MacBook, and even though my laptop doesn't support DDR3 since it's DDR3-L and it showed an error on startup, but upon continueing into Windows it just works and I got 6GB of RAM which appears to be enough for everything to run smoothly.

My conclusion: If you have an old computer and the disk is super slow and constantly in use, you probably simply need more RAM for the latest OS. Consider buying some or using some from another device laying around, this speeds everything up by a LOT.

Answer (score 3):

Try a [minimal version of Linux](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-distro-space/).

Windows has *far too many* processes running in the background, such as indexing and anti-malware scans, which you can forgo in Linux. Even a [full Ubuntu desktop installation](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) can run in 4 GB, though it would benefit from more RAM. For v. 22.04, recommendations are, "2 GHz dual-core processor or better 4 GB system memory."

Many Windows applications are also available in Linux versions. Ubuntu desktop comes with native versions of the full LibreOffice suite, Thunderbird email client and Firefox web browser. [There are numerous other multi-platform apps.](https://www.linuxtrainingacademy.com/reddit-linux-alternatives-for-windows-applications/) Many other Windows apps run well under wine in Linux, such as IrfanView, 7-Zip and PDF-XChange Editor.

Another reason to leave Windows 10 is [EOL is looming](https://endoflife.date/windows), and there will be no more security patches. Ubuntu, as an example, has a [prospective 5 or 10 year life cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) for long-term releases.

Comment: You're totally right about the bloated Windows. I installed Kali Linux on the laptop a couple years ago but can't play Minecraft Bedrock edition on that. The Linux installation is super fast and lightweight. I am not used to using Linux on a daily basis even though I want to but I have been using Windows since I was 10 so I got very used to it. I don't mind EOL since that doesn't mean the operating will stop working, it'll just stop receiving updates but I don't care about security since I have never had malware and I want it to work offline. Linux is a great option for old computers!

Comment: @Foxyz, Linux has come a *long* way in developing friendly graphic user interfaces! If you could get Kali working at all, give another, easier-to-use distro a try. A 75 year old relative o mine has switched completely from Windows to Linux, and she has no intention of going back. As for games, look in the wine database: https://appdb.winehq.org/ . Regrettably, Minecraft is shown *not*usable, though.

Comment: I booted from Kali Live using a usb stick and the internal disk can suddenly go at 110MB/s. Never seen this thing go at such speed even when it was new, it's 20MB/s faster than the highest it would ever go on Windows. I have Windows 11 installed alongisde the older 8.1 and 10 installations and it's also super slow. The problem with Windows is that it uses a pagefile constantly. Solution for an old computer is thus, either use windows ReadyBoost and disable the pagefile on main HDD, expand RAM so it doesn't need pagefile or use Linux!

Comment: There must be some way to reduce Windows processes, although I imagine finding all the places to turn off services and such must be a pain. I recall back with Windows 3.1 I did it the quick and dirty way by renaming system executables until something would break.  Got it to the point where I could spin the hard drive down and run from battery until I needed to actually save.